# Check if main window of application is open and loaded

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, window, mainwindow

Part of my app is opening applications and preserving the work space that they have opened in. My problem is checking if the main application window has opened so I can go and switch to the next work space. Normally, I could just check if A window if that app was open, but for some apps such as IntelliJ IDEA, there is a loading window that is not main, but still shows up in `CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo()`. I check if a window of the app is open, then check if it has a title. This works for the IntelliJ IDEA apps, but applications like calculator that have main window of the apps without a window title, the code goes into an infinite wait loop. I have googled around and have not come up with anything, and this is one of the last things that needs to be fixed in my app.

**Will add code later (when I have my computer)**

**TL;DR:**

I need to check if the main window of an app is open. (Apps like INtelliJ IDEA have a loading window, and the window needs to be preserved in a work space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much testing, I have come up with an answer if anyone else needs it.

I used the accessibility framework, and the code is as follows:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfWindowsOpenFromApplicationWithPID:(NSInteger)PID
{
    NSInteger count = 0; // For return.
    AXUIElementRef anApp = AXUIElementCreateApplication((pid_t)PID);
    CFTypeRef aChildren;
    AXUIElementCopyAttributeValue(anApp, kAXChildrenAttribute, &aChildren);

    SafeCFRelease(anApp);
    if (aChildren) {
        for (NSInteger i = 0; i < CFArrayGetCount(aChildren); i++) {
            AXUIElementRef aChild = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(aChildren, i);
            // Get subrole
            CFTypeRef aSubrole;
            AXUIElementCopyAttributeValue(aChild, kAXSubroleAttribute, &aSubrole);

            NSString *aSubroleString = CFBridgingRelease(aSubrole);
            if (aSubroleString) {
                // Not a menu :3
                if ([aSubroleString isEqualToString:@"AXStandardWindow"]) {
                    count++;
                }
            }
        }

        SafeCFRelease(aChildren);
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
    return count;
}
```

This code return the number of (main) windows open for an app with PID in the current workspace. I then get the AXApplication from the PID, and then I get the children from it. As seen in the Accessibility Inspector:

[image: inspector]

The children are the windows and the menubar. The main windows have a subrole of `AXStandardWindow`. My code loops through the children, and then checks the subrole.